# Pandas parallel apply with koalas (pyspark)

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, dask, spark-koalas

I'm new to Koalas (pyspark), and I was trying to utilize Koalas for parallel apply, but it seemed like it was using a single core for the whole operation (correct me if I'm wrong) and ended up using dask for parallel apply (using map_partition) which worked pretty well.

However, I would like to know if there's a way to utilize Koalas for parallel apply.

I used basic codes for operation like below.

```
import pandas as pd
import databricks.koalas as ks

my_big_data = ks.read_parquet('my_big_file') # file is single partitioned parquet file

my_big_data['new_column'] = my_big_data['string_column'].apply(my_prep) # my_prep does stirng operations


my_big_data.to_parquet('my_big_file_modified') # for Koalas does lazy evaluation
```

Comment: It sounds strange that it doesn't parallelize the job. Take a look in the [official API page](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/best_practices.html) and try to set manually the `spark.executor.cores` with the number of cores which you want.

Comment: @ggeop I'm running Koalas with the default setting, but do you mean that ```spark.executor.cores``` needs to be changed in order to make it parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a link that discuss this problem. https://github.com/databricks/koalas/issues/1280

If the number of rows that are being applied by function is less than `1,000` (default value), then `pandas dataframe` will be called to do the operation.

The user defined function above `my_prep` is applied to each row, so single core `pandas` was being used.

In order to force it to work in pyspark (parallel) manner, user should modify the configuration as below.

```
import databricks.koalas as ks
ks.set_option('compute.default_index_type','distributed') # when .head() call is too slow
ks.set_option('compute.shortcut_limit',1) # Koalas will apply pyspark
```

Also, explicitly specifying type (type hint) in the user defined function will make Koalas not to go shortcut path and will make parallel.

```
def my_prep(row) -> string:
  return row

kdf['my_column'].apply(my_prep)
```